# How do I run doctests?

Tags: plutustx, plutus-starter

I copied the plutus-starter template: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter and created a file `BasicPlutusTx.hs` (and added it under `exposed-modules` in the `.cabal` file).

Then I started copying over all the code from the introductory tutorial: https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/tutorials/plutus-tx.html
which includes doctests. What do I need to add to the `.cabal` file to run these doctests?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

To run `doctest`, you don't need to add that to your cabal file. You need to install the `doctest` executable, and then run `cabal repl --with-ghc=doctest`. See the [doctest documentation](https://github.com/sol/doctest).

Comment: IIUC, I can only use things that are installed with Nix in this project. How do I find and install the doctest package for Nix?